# Is NoSQL just a marketing buzz on top of RDBMS from Software Design Perspective?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

From architectural perspective: Could you please help me understand why NoSQL DynamoDB is so [hype](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).

> DynamoDB supports some of the world’s largest scale applications by
> providing consistent, single-digit millisecond response times at any
> scale.

I'm trying to critic, in order to understand WHY part of the question.
We always have to specify partition Key and key attribute while retrieving to get millisecond of performance

If I design RDBMS:

1. where primary key or alternate key (INDEXED) always needs to be specified by in the query
2. I can use partition key to find out in which database my data is stored.
3. Never do JOINs

> Isn't it same as NoSQL kind of architecture without any marketing buzz around it?

We're shifting to DynamoDB anyways but this is my innocent curiosity, there must be a strong reason which RDMBS can't do. Let's skip backup and maintenance advantages etc.

Answer (score 6):

You are conflating two different things.

### The definition of NoSQL

There isn't one, at least not one that can apply in all cases.

In most uses, NoSQL databases don't force your data into the fixed-schema "rows and columns" of a relational database. Although modern relational databases, such as Postgres, support data types such as JSONB that would have E. F. Codd spinning in his grave.

DynamoDB is a document database: it is optimized for retrieving and updating *single* documents based on a unique key, and it does not restrict the fields that those documents contain (other than requiring the ones used for a key).

### Distributed Databases

A distributed database stores data on multiple nodes, and is able to perform parallel queries on those nodes and combine the results.

There are distributed SQL database: Redshift and BigQuery are optimized for queries against large datasets that may include joins, while MySQL (and no doubt others) which can run multiple engines and distribute the queries between them. It is possible for SQL databases to perform joins, including joins that cross nodes, but such joins generally perform poorly.

DynamoDB distributes items on shards based on their partition key. This makes it very fast for retrieving single items, because the query can be directed to a single shard. It is much less performant when scanning for items that reside on multiple shards.

As you note in your question, you *can* implement a sharded document DB on top of a relational database (either using native JSON columns or storing everything in a CLOB that is parsed for each access). But enough other people have done this (including DynamoDB) that it doesn't make sense (to me, at least) to re-implement.

Comment: thanks seems like having schemaless behavior is the distinguishing feature of NoSQL. Thanks for bringing BigQuery into picture as well.